Can not obtain the paths from the <Polygon> TS component. (in @react-google-maps/api )
I am trying to obtain the paths of the Polygon component provided by this library upon essentially updating the component. Here is my code:
IMPORTANT NOTE: the library I am using is @react-google-maps/api
import { PolygonProps, Polygon } from '@react-google-maps/api'
import { createPolygon } from './GeoMapFunctions.ts'
import { useReduxSelector } from '../../store/ReduxHooks.ts'
import { useCallback, useRef } from 'react'

const CustomPolygon = () => {
    const { shapeCharacteristics } = useReduxSelector(
        state => state.geoMapSlice
    )

    const polygonRef = useRef<Polygon>()

    const basePath = createPolygon(
        shapeCharacteristics!.center,
        shapeCharacteristics!.sides ?? 4,
        shapeCharacteristics!.radius > 0.1 ? 0.01 : shapeCharacteristics!.radius
    )

    const handleEditPolygon = () => {
        // AT.1
        const { paths } = polygonRef.current as PolygonProps
        console.log('the paths: ', paths)

        // AT.2
        let aa = polygonRef.current as PolygonProps | null
        console.log('A: ', aa)
        console.log('A-type: ', typeof aa)

        // AT.3
        const polygon: PolygonProps = polygonRef.current as PolygonProps
        if (polygon) {
            console.log('the polygon: ', polygon)
            if ('paths' in polygon) {
                const polygonProps = polygon as PolygonProps
                console.log('PolygonProps:', polygonProps)
                // Access polygon properties here
            } else {
                console.log('Not a PolygonProps object.')
            }
        } else {
            console.log('Polygon not available.')
        }
    }

    const onLoad = useCallback((ref: any) => (polygonRef.current = ref), [])
    return (
        <Polygon
            onLoad={onLoad}
            onMouseUp={handleEditPolygon}
            onDragEnd={handleEditPolygon}
            draggable={true}
            editable={true}
            paths={basePath}
            options={{
                strokeColor: 'black',
                fillColor: 'black',
                fillOpacity: 0.5
            }}
        />
    )
}

export default CustomPolygon

I had this issue previously with the  component however, there I`ve managed to solve this issue with an identical approach
let circleRef = useRef<Circle>()
const draggedCircle = (circleEventObject: google.maps.MapMouseEvent) => {
        if (circleEventObject.latLng) {
            dispatch(setShapeCenter(circleEventObject.latLng.toJSON()))
        }
    }

    const handleRadiusChange = () => {
        const circleProps = circleRef.current as CircleProps | null

        if (circleProps !== null) {
            console.log('CircleProps prop radius !!!!: ', circleProps?.radius)
            if (circleProps?.radius) {
                dispatch(setShapeRadius(circleProps?.radius))
            }
        }
    }
    const onLoad = useCallback((ref: any) => (circleRef.current = ref), [])

    return (
        <Circle
            onLoad={onLoad}
            draggable={true}
            editable={true}
            center={shapeCharacteristics!.center}
            radius={shapeCharacteristics!.radius}
            onDragEnd={draggedCircle}
            onRadiusChanged={handleRadiusChange}
            options={{
                strokeColor: 'red',
                fillColor: 'red',
                fillOpacity: 0.05
            }}
        />
    )

The reference of the Polygon is a very weird object, when expanded recursively it expands to a very large object

I have found a potential solution here: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/reactgooglemapsapi-editing-a-polygon-popr2?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js%3A86%2C31, however, this is a JS solution and I was not able to "convert" it to Type Script, I quickly run into the same issue.
I would very much appreciate if someone could help me understand how to solve this issue, thank you in advance.

I don't know much about that library and the official documentation link that I found is broken. How about polygon.getPath() or polygon.getPaths() (if your polygons have multiple paths)?

Your suggestion was nearly correct, below I have posted a working solution, if you interested have a look at it ;)

I have found a solution based on the link provided into the question itself: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/reactgooglemapsapi-editing-a-polygon-popr2?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js%3A86%2C31, I`ve essentially converted the JS code to TS code and all it works fine.
Credit goes to this Stackoverflow answer, where I have found this link: How do I get to the updated path of an editable PolyLine from react-google-maps/api?
Here is the same component with the updated changes:
import { useState, useRef, useCallback } from 'react'
import { Polygon } from '@react-google-maps/api'
import { createPolygon } from './GeoMapFunctions.ts'
import { useReduxDispatch, useReduxSelector } from '../../store/ReduxHooks.ts'
import { setShapeCoordinates } from '../../store/GeoMapSlice.ts'
import { PolygonEdge } from '../filtering/FilterTypes.ts'

const CustomPolygon = () => {
    const dispatch = useReduxDispatch()
    const { shapeCharacteristics } = useReduxSelector(
        state => state.geoMapSlice
    )

    const initialPaths = createPolygon(
        shapeCharacteristics!.center,
        shapeCharacteristics!.sides ?? 4,
        0.01
    )
    const [path, setPath] = useState<google.maps.LatLngLiteral[]>(initialPaths)

    const polygonRef = useRef<google.maps.Polygon | null>(null)
    const listenersRef = useRef<google.maps.MapsEventListener[]>([])

    const onEdit = useCallback(() => {
        if (polygonRef.current) {
            const nextPath = polygonRef.current
                .getPath()
                .getArray()
                .map(latLng => {
                    return { lat: latLng.lat(), lng: latLng.lng() }
                })
            const orderedCoordinates: PolygonEdge[] = nextPath.map(
                (path, index) => ({
                    order: index + 1,
                    longitude: path.lng,
                    latitude: path.lat
                })
            )
            dispatch(setShapeCoordinates(orderedCoordinates))
            setPath(nextPath)
        }
    }, [dispatch])

    const onLoad = useCallback(
        (polygon: google.maps.Polygon) => {
            polygonRef.current = polygon
            const path = polygon.getPath()
            listenersRef.current.push(
                path.addListener('set_at', onEdit),
                path.addListener('insert_at', onEdit),
                path.addListener('remove_at', onEdit)
            )
        },
        [onEdit]
    )

    const onUnmount = useCallback(() => {
        listenersRef.current.forEach(listener => listener.remove())
        polygonRef.current = null
    }, [])

    return (
        <Polygon
            editable
            draggable
            path={path}
            onMouseUp={onEdit}
            onDragEnd={onEdit}
            onLoad={onLoad}
            onUnmount={onUnmount}
        />
    )
}

export default CustomPolygon

